# .on('keyup', function(){ to trigger only on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup, onkeyup

I want this to trigger only on keyup and not before. Can anyone help please?

```
$(function() {
$('#acf-field_5a32085c7df98-field_5a3208f87df99').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#link-headline-fb').text($(this).val());
}).keyup();   
});
```

It is currently displaying empty text before `keyup`, yet I want this to display the default PHP value unless text is changed. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: `#acf-field_5a32085c7df98-field_5a3208f87df99` wow

Comment: Why do you have `.keyup()` after the event handler?

Comment: Maybe that is as it displays the default PHP when removed. However, then if the field is populated in the database it does not show. I'll accept this answer and add another question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are invoking a `keyup` event after you attach your event listener. Remove `.keyup()` like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('#acf-field_5a32085c7df98-field_5a3208f87df99').on('keyup', function() {
        $('#link-headline-fb').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#acf-field_5a32085c7df98-field_5a3208f87df99').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#link-headline-fb').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="link-headline-fb">
</div>
<input id="acf-field_5a32085c7df98-field_5a3208f87df99" />
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/dj7yqyec/

As a side note, I find `$(document).ready(` to be far clearer than `$(function () {`. The latter looks too much like an IIFE.